# Does one flink application has only one job id

Tags: apache-flink

I am using `flink run -m yarn-cluster -c my.Main` to submit an application to the yarn cluster， the code contains several operators that trigger computation(let me name it `action operator`)，like `collect` and others

My question is: I would ask whether one action operator will produce a job id, that is, one application may have many job ids; or all the action operators in the application will have only one job id?

My understanding is it looks to me that the whole application has only one JobGraph, thus there is only one job id(got from JobGragh.getJobID)

Comment: There is only one job id if you only use one environment(calling environment.execute() once).

Comment: Thanks @bupt_ljy. Then it is different from spark, each action operator trigger has a corresponding  job id.